# Flutter Android doesn't generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

Tags: android, flutter, macos

When running flutter run or building the application for using Third Party plugins, Flutter is supposed to generate the file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` under `app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins`.

> The AndroidManifest contains the:

```xml
<meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

> One additional information is that, i tried to setup it on a new computer and it is not working, this was working on another Mac Silicon. I tried to delete it in the other MacSilicon and stopped working.

`flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale en-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.10.4 on channel stable at /Users/andy/flutter
    • Upstream repository ssh://git@github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • FLUTTER_GIT_URL = ssh://git@github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 682aa387cf (5 weeks ago), 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/andy/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/andy/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Users/andy/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.9971841/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Users/andy/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.9971841/Android
      Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Users/andy/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.10121639/Android
      Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/andy/Applications/JetBrains Toolbox/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/andy/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/231.9011.34/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/andy/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/231.9161.38/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.68.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64 • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64  • macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: foo
description: Foo

version: 8.2.1+83
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  adapty_flutter: ^2.4.1
  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.3
  bloc: ^8.1.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  collection: ^1.17.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  darq: ^1.2.1
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  euc: ^1.0.6+8
  firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.16
  flex_color_picker: ^3.1.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  flutter_i18n: ^0.33.0
  flutter_iconpicker_plus: ^3.2.3
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.4.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_reorderable_list: ^1.3.1
  flutter_swipe_action_cell: ^3.1.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.3.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.2
  html: ^0.15.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  image_picker: ^0.8.7
  in_app_review: ^2.0.6
  intl: ^0.18.0
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
  optional: ^6.1.0+1
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path: ^1.8.2
  permission_handler: ^10.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.5
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.5
  sentry_flutter: ^7.1.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.18
  string_validator: ^1.0.0
  the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  version: ^3.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  bloc_test: ^9.1.1
  faker: ^2.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mocktail: ^0.3.0
  very_good_analysis: ^4.0.0

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/icon_transparent.png
  color: "#58506e"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  plugin:
    platforms:
      ios:
        default_package: webview_flutter_wkwebview

  assets:
    - assets/images/icon_transparent.png
    - assets/images/hoshimon_ads.jpg
    - assets/images/mountains.jpg
    - assets/images/line_logo.png
    - assets/flutter_i18n/en.json
    - assets/flutter_i18n/ja.json
    - assets/images/tutorial/ja/extracted.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/ja/list.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/ja/share_highlight.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/ja/share_highlight_button.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/ja/share_other_selection.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/ja/share_settings_highlight_app.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/en/extracted.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/en/list.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/en/share_highlight.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/en/share_highlight_button.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/en/share_other_selection.png
    - assets/images/tutorial/en/share_settings_highlight_app.png
    - assets/images/rating/heart.png
    - assets/images/rating/heart_empty.png
    - assets/images/rating/heart_half.png
    - assets/images/subscription_thank_you.png
```

The File to be Generated and the Plugins are integrated. I Already tried to:

- Reinstall Flutter
- Reinstall Flutter and Dart Plugin for Android Studio
- Try to different IDE like VSCode or Even running on terminal
- Try different JDK versions, 17,18,20.
- Try to run gradlew clean and gradlew build
- Rename the Project or move the project from folders
- flutter clean && flutter pub get
- flutter pub cache clean
- Deleted all cached files such as `.dart_tool`, `.gradle`.
- Deleted the local repository and tried to clone again via git clone in a fresh folder
- Invalidate Cache of the Editors and IDEs
- Upgrade dependencies

Comment: This is the statement causing the issue but it is not clear yet what is the root cause:

```
 plugin:
    platforms:
      ios:
        default_package: webview_flutter_wkwebview
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement in the `pubspec.yml` is overriding the platform of the application and treating the flutter app as a package.

```
  plugin:
    platforms:
      ios:
        default_package: webview_flutter_wkwebview
```